# multiple indexing and finding mode of cell array

Tags: matlab, indexing, cell-array, mode

I have an array of integers called `indices` and a cell array of strings called `Categories`. How do I find the most frequent string out of only the cells in the array `indices`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unique` to find the mode of a cell array by finding the mode of the third output and use that to index into the first output of `unique`. To determine the mode of only the elements specified by `indices`, you'll want to grab just the subset of elements of `Categories` indicated by `indices` and pass those to `unique`.

```
[values, ~, inds] = unique(Categories(indices));
modeValue = values{mode(inds)};
```

Comment: Perfect didn't think to use unique thanks will accept this answer when it allows